# Converting jQuery's CSS timing to ms

Tags: javascript, css, regex

When asking jQuery for a duration in CSS, it returns this value in seconds, e.g. `1.2s`. Example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/BramVanroy/8t3s1rj5/).

```
var d = $("div"),
    propDur = d.css("animation-duration"),
    propDurArr = propDur.replace(" ","").split(","),
    propDel = d.css("animation-delay"),
    propDelArr = propDel.replace(" ","").split(",");

console.log(propDurArr[propDurArr.length - 1]);
console.log(propDelArr[propDelArr.length - 1]);
```

Two questions for this:

1. Is this cross-browser? Does jQuery (or better: the browser) always return the value in seconds, or do some browsers prefer a ms representation?
2. How do I convert this value in jQuery/JS to ms (without `ms`)? For example: `1.2s` -> `1200`.

For `2.` you can easily remove the dot, like so:

```
propDel.replace(/(\s|.)/g,"").split(",")
```

But how do I make a condition like this:

```
if  string contains dot
     ADD 00
if  string does NOT contain dot
     ADD 000
```

Please reply to 1 and 2.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I decided to go with @RobG's comment that he hasn't posted as answer yet, so here goes. Quite simple and effective:

```js
function toMS(s) {
    return parseFloat(s) * (/\ds$/.test(s) ? 1000 : 1);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This is only an answer to question #2. You can use `parseFloat()` to get the numerical representation, up to the first non-number (or dot) character. So, `parseFloat("1.2s")*1000` returns 1200, while `parseFloat("1s")*1000` returns 1000.

Answer (score 2):

Check [this solution](https://gist.github.com/jakebellacera/9261266) to convert css time to millisecond:

```
function css_time_to_milliseconds(time_string) {
   var num = parseFloat(time_string, 10),
       unit = time_string.match(/m?s/),
       milliseconds;

   if (unit) {
       unit = unit[0];
   }

   switch (unit) {
       case "s": // seconds
           milliseconds = num * 1000;
           break;
       case "ms": // milliseconds
           milliseconds = num;
           break;
       default:
           milliseconds = 0;
           break;
   }

   return milliseconds;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

1) The animation can either be in seconds or milliseconds - do not expect it to always be one or the other. The suffix will either be `s` or `ms`.

2) As for converting:

```
// provided `value` contains what you got from jQuery
var multiply = value.indexOf('ms') !== -1 ? 1 : 1000;
var converted = parseInt(parseFloat(value) * multiply, 10);
// converted now contains the value in millseconds
```